# How do I increase the refresh rate to 240Hz with a GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER?

Tags: display, screen, samsung, nvidia-geforce

Devices:

- Samsung Odyssey G9 Monitor (5,120 x 1,440)
- GeForce RTX 2070 Super (Display Port)

It seems limited at 120hz, I was wondering how I can enable 240hz.

There also does not seem to be any settings to enable HDR & g-sync, any advice on these 3 points would be greatly appreciated.

```
1. Set refresh rate to 240hz
2. Enable HDR
3. Enable g-sync
```

---

**Current Driver:**
[image: Current Driver]

**xrandr:** the `xrandr` output (only showing connected results):

```bsh
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5120 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-4 connected primary 5120x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1mm x 1mm
   3840x1080     59.97 + 239.97   119.97  
   5120x1440    120.00*   59.98  
   2560x1440    239.90   120.00    59.95  
   2560x1080    119.88    60.00    59.94  
   1920x1080    119.88    60.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
```

The connection between my screen is via the Display Port provided with my monitor, as far as support goes, on Windows I run fine using 240Hz and HDR enabled.

Comment: What Nvidia driver version are you using? What does `xrandr` return (add to your question , please)?

Comment: 5120x1440 @ 240Hz is a lot of bandwidth. Make sure all the cables and ports support it. You probably can't use any kind of adapter.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I have added the driver as well as the the `xrandr` output to my original post.

Comment: @Nmath - It should not be any cable-related issues, I run fine on windows at 240Hz with HDR enabled. So support should not be an issue.

Comment: Do you have the option of trying HDMI, just to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: Hey guys.. any update on that? Are there newer (developer/beta) nvidia drivers what can run on 240hz.. I've been using it on 120hz for some time now (Pop-OS) but every time I boot to Windows I get spoiled with the 240hz smoothness 

I'm running it with nVidia 2080 super

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is limitation of current drivers (nvidia driver 455.45.01). I tried everything, even managed to compile nvidia driver 455.45.01 with kernel 5.10

Comment: I own g9 and i tried 2 cards rtx 2060 and rtx3090

Comment: dont waste time with hdmi on g9  it does not support 5120x1440 @ 240Hz